# Can't access web domain on Win7 PC, how to find what is causing the block?

Tags: windows-7, networking, connection, domain-name

I've got a Win7 PC and when I try to hit a particular web domain I get a generic "network could not connect" issue.

I know that the link and domain work properly because I can hit it on other computers and mobile devices on the same network as my Win7 PC.

I'm wondering what would be the best ways to go about finding out how and what is causing the communication lapse.

I've tried to do something like `ping` in `cmd` but it just times out and I also tried `flushdns` but that did not resolve the error.

Are there any other commands or things I can do to check out what causes the link to not work?

Comment: Have you checked to see if it is blocked by your browser, firewall or other security software?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I taken a look at security software and browser issues. The link and domain don't work on any browsers so it's not browser specific. I'll keep looking maybe I passed over something in the security software.

Comment: Is anything in your hosts file that points to that domain?  It could contain a hard-coded wrong IP address which would cause the browser to visit that IP instead of the one the DNS server provides.

Answer (score 0):

From what I remember this problem was caused by a browser extension that was meant to 'speed up' internet connections but somehow had a faulty gateway for the domain in question.